# Google Finance function returns Date not Currency Conversion

Tags: google-sheets, google, google-finance

I am trying to calculate the USD:AUD conversion from M3 and show the result of the current conversion rate in the next cell, but it is only resolving the date

I am trying to get cell M3 to convert to AUD in cell N3

```
=M2*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:USDAUD")
```

This formula has worked in the cell above and converted the "live" rate, but when I amend it for other cells it throws up a random date such as 27/01/1900.

I have another part of the spreadsheet which converts the currency on a particular date, this however needs to be current and update itself with the live prices whenever I check it.

anyone able to help?

Answer (score 1):

When it throws up a random date, try selecting the cell and choosing *Format* →  *Number* → *Number*.